# Linux find and rsync: how to find and rsync keeping the directories?

Tags: linux, find, rsync

How can I find files from a directory and save those files in the subdirectories it was found in?

**FileDirectory:**

- TestFolder

  - Folder1

    - FileFromFolder1.txt
  - Folder2

    - FileFromFolder2.txt
  - Folder3

    - FileFromFolder3.txt

Currently using this script:

```
find TestFolder -type f -newermt '2021-04-01 10:15:00' ! -newermt '2021-04-30 10:15:00' -exec rsync -avz {} /home/user/save/FilesSaved/ \;
```

This will search in my subdirectories and pull out files and save it individually into FileSaved directory.

Inside FileSaved Directory:

- FileFromFolder1.txt
- FileFromFolder2.txt
- FileFromFolder3.txt

I want it to store into folders where it was found ex:

FileSaved Directory:

```
 - Folder1        
     - FileFromFolder1.txt
 - Folder2
     - FileFromFolder2.txt
 - Folder3
     - FileFromFolder3.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `-R` to your `rsync` flags (not having tested this).

Comment: it will need `(cd src && find . ...)` instead of `find src ...`

Comment: Well that was embarrassing... I have been using an lower case R =/. Thank you so much